# How can I use scala generators to generate date with range?

Tags: java, scala, scalatest, scalacheck

Im using scalacheck so I will be able to use Generators.

So In my generator class I have stuff like:

```
invType <- Gen.oneOf(Seq("Communication", "Restaurants", "Parking"))
invoiceNumber <- Gen.choose(1, 10000)
```

But now I want to generate:

```
 invoiceDate = "1/1/2014" //todo: generate random date between 2013 - today
```

How can I do this?
tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can generate the full range of dates, then you should be able to use `Gen.oneOf` to randomly select a date from that range.  You can generate the range with a piece of code like this:

```
  val sf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy")
  val now = new Date
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  cal.set(2013, 0, 1) //Jan 1 2013

  val dates = 
    Iterator.
      continually{
        val d = cal.getTime
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
        sf.format(d)
      }.
      takeWhile(_ => cal.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTime).
      toSeq
```

Then from there you should be able to do:

```
invDate <- Gen.oneOf(dates)
```

Comment: I need it as a string

Comment: @Joe, I modified to generate it as a String